# Java Android Date returns wrong GetDay() for Friday

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have a class where I need to keep track of 7 date objects, one for each day of the week that holds a time.

I set up a calendar like this and assign it to a Date object

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);

Date FridayOpen = cal.getTime();

Log.i("Creation Day", String.valueOf(FridayOpen.toString()));

Log.i("Creation Day2", String.valueOf(FridayOpen.getDay()));
```

And the `LogCat` results are

```
Creation Day = Fri Dec 07 00:30:00 CST 2012

Creation Day2 = 5
```

WHY IS IT RETURNING 5 when Friday is clearly day 6 and stored in my Date Object? I can't switch `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` when the date is off. I've spent hours on this stupid problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because days are from 0 to 6 .
0 for Sunday and 6 for Saturday.

**Edit** `getDay()` Method is Deprecated use `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`.

Answer (score 1):

See the getDay method of the Date class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay%28%29

Friday is 5

also it is deprecated so shouldnt be used